Allow both query OR route model binding with ASP.NET Core Web API
I've got an HttpGet on an API method with primitive parameters and would like to provide the option of passing parameters via the query OR route. I've just trashed half a day building various custom binders and such trying to figure this out to no avail.
I'd like this method to work with both /GetMyData/1 and /GetMyData?id=1
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMyData/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetMyData(int id)
{
    return await _dataService.GetMyData(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

If I set to [Route("GetMyData")] then /GetMyData?id=1 works. If I set to [Route("GetMyData/{id}")] then /GetMyData/1 works. But if I have [Route("GetMyData")][Route("GetMyData/{id}")] then only /GetMyData/1 works.
What am I missing here? I'm working with an ApiController in ASP.NET Core 8.

As far as I know this is not possible. The parameter is either [FromRoute] or [FromQuery]. I suggest to outsource the body of the current method into a new method, create a second route with the query string parameter signature and call the new method from both routes.

Use [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int id { get; set; }  Then create two methods one with route set to [Route("GetMyData/{id}")] and has GetMyData(int id).... the other with [Route("GetMyData")] and has GetMyData()... no args.

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this approach, but it works:
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMyData")]
[Route("GetMyData/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetMyData(
    [FromRoute(Name = "id")]int? idFromRoute,
    [FromQuery(Name = "id")]int idFromQuery)
{
    var id = idFromRoute ?? idFromQuery;

    return await _dataService.GetMyData(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

The main issue (besides how clunky it looks), is that you can still call the route without passing either value and it will default idFromQuery to 0. If you want to handle that as well, make both arguments nullable and do something if id is still null after the assignment, like returning a Bad Request.
Having said that, I would look into alternatives such as just leveraging OData and allowing the id to be a filter on the main endpoint so both of these would work:

/MyData/{id}
/MyData?$filter=Id eq {id}


You can unify the two cases in the same method by defining the parameter as an optional type such as int? id. This allows you to unify the two /GetMyData/1  /GetMyData?id=1 cases in the same method:
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMyData/{id?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetMyData( int? id)
{
             
     return Ok(id);
}

This is my test result:



I came across this possible solution when hunting around though it's not working for me.  It doesn't pick up the querystring and ends up passing null.

I suppose an alternative would be to access the query string via HttpContext though that is a bit hacky.

You can check the routing configuration to see if it overrides or modifies the default ASP.NET Core routing behavior. Make sure the routing configuration in program.cs is correct. ASP.NET Core uses routing templates to match request URLs and extract parameter values ​​based on the templates. If the routing configuration is incorrect, the parameters may not be parsed correctly.
